# Jekyll App in Google App Engine throws error 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: ruby, google-app-engine, jekyll

I'm trying to deploy a simple Jekyll app in Google App Engine and it keeps throwing a 502 Bad Gateway error. This is my code: https://github.com/voiladt/voiladt.github.io

When I launch it from the GC console it works perfectly, I simply use: `bundle exec jekyll serve -P 8080`.

But when I deploy it with `gcloud app deploy` it takes a very long time (about 30 minutes) and the resulting website throws a 502 error from nginx.

The logs don't seem to be of much help:

`...
Configuration file: /app/_config.yml
Invalid theme folder: _includes
            Source: /app
       Destination: /app/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
     Build Warning: Layout 'post' requested in _posts/2018-12-30-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown does not exist.
     Build Warning: Layout 'page' requested in about.md does not exist.
                    done in 0.767 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/app'
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:8080/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
"GET /" 502
"GET /" 502
"GET /" 502`

I've tried replacing the hostname to `localhost` and to `0.0.0.0`, but nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set the hostname to 0.0.0.0 and the port to 8080.

I had tried 0.0.0.0 before, but I had the default port (4000 for jekyll).

To set the port: In the `app.yaml`, set `entrypoint: bundle exec jekyll serve -P $PORT`.

To set the hostname: In `_config.yaml`, set `host: "0.0.0.0"`.

Comment: Good job finding the solution! Do you know that you can accept your own answer?